# ray cylinder intersection formula

Tags: math, graphics, computational-geometry, intersection, raytracing

I am working on a simple raytracer, and I need to find a cylinder intersection, I found an equation that works for me. Still, I don't understand the math behind it, the formula is:

To hit a cylinder we notice that:

[image: cylinder formula that I use]

I use the website below formula:
https://hugi.scene.org/online/hugi24/coding%20graphics%20chris%20dragan%20raytracing%20shapes.htm

can anyone please explain this formula until finding a and b and c?
and thanks in advance.

some extra info:
The vector dot product is denoted with "|".

len(V) is the length of vector V.

dot(V) is the square length of vector V (dot product with itself).

Definition of cylinder:

C is the start cap point of the cylinder.

V is a unit length vector that determines the cylinder's axis.

r is the cylinder's radius.

Comment: Please state what information is given (for the cylinder geometry for example) and what the expected output (just the hit point, the normal, the distance) etc.. Also explain the **A** | **V** notation and what the symbols mean.

Comment: If you decompose your line to express it in terms of a component along the principal axis of the cylinder components in the plane normal to the axis, (transform it as necessary - express the line in terms of the cylinder's model space) then it just becomes intersection of a line and a circle in 2D, and you can substitute the parameter of the line to get the axial component of the intersection (height).  You just have to handle the case where the ray is parallel to the cylinder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found My answer, I will try to explain it as much as I can:

It is assumed that you have basic knowledge of vector mathematics. I use here a few simplifications:

- Vector dot product is denoted with "|".
- len(V) is the length of vector V.
- dot(V) is the square length of vector V (dot product with itself).

A ray is defined in the following way:

```
P = O + D*t
```

I will use a substitution for the P equation:

```
P - C = D*t + X
```

where C is a center point of a Cylinder and X equals O-C.

O - C: subtract the center of the cylinder from the ray origin to turn the problem into a (0,0,0) coordinate.

[image: cylinder and ray intersection paint]

Definition:

- C is the start cap point of the cylinder
- V is a unit length vector that determines the cylinder's axis
- r is the cylinder's radius
- maxim determines the cylinder's end cap point

To hit a cylinder we notice that:

```
A = C + V*m
( P-A )|V = 0
   len( P-A ) = r
```

where m is a scalar that determines the closest point on the axis to the hit point. The P-A vector is perpendicular to V, which guarantees the closest distance to the axis. P-A is the cylinder's radius.

Solution:

```
(P-C-V*m)|V = 0
```

because p -c is perpendicular to V.

we need to find m?

(P-C)|V = m*(V|V)

let (len(V)=1)

```
m = (P-C)|V
```

we have : p - c = D *t + x

so:

```
m = (D*t+X)|V
```

expand result we reach:

```
m = D|V*t + X|V
```

let's solve the equation of the cylinder now:

```
len(P-C-V*m) = r
```

replace m and p-c with their values, we reach:

```
dot( D*t+X - V*(D|V*t + X|V) ) = r^2
```

because the dot product of a vector with itself is the square of that vector.

we factorize with (t) we get:

```
dot( (D-V*(D|V))*t + (X-V*(X|V)) ) = r^2
```

we have a general rule if we start with something like:

```
dot( A-V*(A|V) )
```

we end up with something like this:

```
A|A - (A|V)^2
```

And then we apply this rule to the line before, and we replace

```
dot( (D-V*(D|V))
```

with:

```
D|D - (D|V)^2
```

where we fill in D and X for A we move from:

```
dot( (D-V*(D|V))*t + (X-V*(X|V)) ) = r^2
```

to:

```
dot( (D|D - (D|V)^2)*t + (X|X - (X|V)^2) ) = r^2
```

so the formula can write as :

```
(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 + 2AB
```

so our final formula is :

```
dot( (D|D - (D|V)^2)*t + (X|X - (X|V)^2) ) = (D|D - (D|V)^2)t^2 + 2 * t * (D-V*(D|V))|(X-V*(X|V)) + (X|X - (X|V)^2)
```

so we reach :

```
(D|D - (D|V)^2)t^2 + 2 * t * (D-V*(D|V))|(X-V*(X|V)) + (X|X - (X|V)^2) - r^2 = 0
```

so this formula is a quadratic formula in form of:

```
a*t^2 + b*t + c = 0
```

that can be solved using:

[image: solution of quadratic formula]

so we can extract the three parameters a, b and c:

```
a = D|D - (D|V)^2

c = X|X - (X|V)^2 - r^2

b = 2 * (D-V*(D|V))|(X-V*(X|V)) =
 = 2 * (D|X - D|V*(X|V) - X|V*(D|V) + (D|V)*(X|V)) =
 = 2 * (D|X - (D|V)*(X|V))
```

I hope this explanation would help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I could not fully adhere to the original notation; I used the dot for both dot product and scalar multiplication. I hope it helps anyway.

Let us first obtain a formula for the distance of a point `P` to the axis of the cylindre, of vector equation `C + m.V`. We find the `m` such that `PC` is orthogonal to `V`, by

```
(PC + m.V).V = 0,
```

giving

```
m = - PC.V.
```

Now, the squared norm of PC is the squared radius and we obtain

```
r² = (PC - (PC.V).V)² = PC² - (PC.V)².
```

If we consider a ray of origin `A` and direction `D`, let `A + t.D`, we have the quadratic equation in `t`

```
r² = (AC + t.D)² - (AC.V + t.D.V)².
```

Remains to expand to obtain the coefficients of the quadratic trinomial.